# Found the old jigsaw sample apple sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I just come across the old jigsaw source that apple used to have on offer. Ive got a few errors when compling just wondered if anyone could help.

I get the error:   error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'endTrackingPiece:position:' error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'continueTrackingPiece:position:'

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch*                touch = [touches anyObject];

    //Check if we have a double-tap in the piece view and notify the application controller or begin tracking piece dragging
    if([touch tapCount] >= 2)
    [(AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] resetPiece:self];
    else {
        _tracking = YES;
        [(AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] beginTrackingPiece:self position:[touch locationInView]];
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch*                touch = [touches anyObject];

    //Continue tracking piece dragging
    if(_tracking)
    [(AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] continueTrackingPiece:self position:[touch locationInView]];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch*                touch = [touches anyObject];

    //Finish tracking piece dragging
    if(_tracking) {
        [(AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] endTrackingPiece:self position:[touch locationInView]];
        _tracking = NO;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do the method definitions for `-endTrackingPiece:position:` and  `-continueTrackingPiece:position:` look like?  `-locationInView` should return a CGPoint, and that hasn't changed since the original release of the iPhone SDK.

Comment: Hi, Its out of context. Can you please post a link to the jigsaw apple sample since looks like apple has removed it form there list. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @user506926 could you please upload the sample code for the jigsaw puzzle or could you mail it to prajulp@gmail.com as i am planning to modify that and make a app of my own.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that locationInView is expecting a UIView * as a parameter, see reference here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

So, for each of those three lines, the fix is to change

```
[touch locationInView]
```

to

```
[touch locationInView: self]
```

Prior to this though, you may need to change the base SDK in the project file, if it's referring to Aspen1.2.sdk, the version I found is. I updated it to iOS4.3 (this is all in XCode 4, I should add.)

If you want to get rid of the deprecation warning as well, change

```
_puzzles = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:path] mutableCopy];
```

to

```
_puzzles = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL] mutableCopy];
```

in AppController.m _resetPuzzle.

After doing the above, I get a cleanly building project which runs in the iOS simulator. Make sure you don't have your volume muted or you will miss the "Yay!" when you complete a puzzle :)